# How to calculate Multistage Filter Design overall cutoff frequency when each stage has different cutoff frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, active-filter

How to calculate Multistage Filter Designs overall cutoff frequency when each stage has own different cutoff frequency

Comment: Thanks to Mr. Matt L. and finally i got my cutoff frequency of multistage HP filter. after solving all transfer function i got overall 6th order cutoff frequency which is exactly match with my result .... also thanks to Mr. Andy aka for your response .i would also try this ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that each stage of the multistage filter is unaffected by stages before or after it i.e. the stages can be thought of of having buffer amps between them thus they are isolated from nuances of other stages.

Take the bode plot of stage 1 and mathematically add it to the bode plot of stage 2. Continue until all the filter stages are plotted and you have an overall frequency response of the multi-stage filter.

Answer (score 2):

In general there's no simple formula to calculate the total cut-off frequency. You would need to consider the total transfer function (i.e. the multiplication of the transfer functions of the individual filters), and from this transfer function compute the 3dB cut-off frequency.